# Running another process without GUI freezing

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm having trouble getting my GUI to appear and not freeze while running (and waiting for) an outside process.  In this case, drivers.exe is a very simply program where the user simply clicks "OK".  So whenever I click OK, it exits.  I am trying to simply make my status strip count numbers up (really fast) as drivers.exe is executing.  But in practice, my GUI never appears at all until drivers.exe exits.

```
private void run_drivers()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Driver");
            int driver_timeout_in_minutes = 20;
            System.Diagnostics.Process driverproc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "drivers.exe");
            driverproc.WaitForExit(driver_timeout_in_minutes * 1000 * 60);   //uses milliseconds, we must convert
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadStart worker = new ThreadStart(run_drivers);
            Console.WriteLine("Main - Creating worker thread");
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "hi";
            Thread t = new Thread(worker);
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Main - Have requested the start of worker thread");

            int i = 0;
            while (t.IsAlive)
            {
                i++;
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = i.ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Dead");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look into a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), as it does all the threading work for you

Comment: Could you please show me how?  I did give it a shot, and it really didn't work at all.  My form still wouldn't show...at all, in fact.

Comment: The problem is the "while(t.IsAlive)" loop. He needs to get that off the UI thread whether he uses BackgroundWorker or not.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your form does not show until drivers.exe has run is because you are running drivers.exe from within `Form.Load`.  `Form.Load` occurs before the form is shown.  Try running drivers.exe in `Form.Shown` instead.

Also, `while(t.IsAlive)` will technically block your UI thread.  If that is not what you want, it should be moved off the main thread.  You will also probably want to call `toolStripStatusLabel1.Refresh()` to force the label to refresh after you set its text.

Comment: Whether the code's running in Form.Load or later, the UI thread will still not get time to paint the screen when executed as shown.

Answer (score 0):

don't put any loop on GUI thread. it will freeze your application. Loop has to be on background thread which should update `toolStripStatusLabel1` through `Invoke` method.

see this example. untested. maybe it might even work just like this...

```
    private void run_drivers()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start Driver");
        int driver_timeout_in_minutes = 20;
        System.Diagnostics.Process driverproc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "drivers.exe");
        int i = 0;
        var action = new Action<int>(x => {  toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = i.ToString(); })
        while (!driverproc.HasExited)
        {
            i++;
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Invoke(action);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Dead");
        // start another thread here...
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart worker = new ThreadStart(run_drivers);
        Console.WriteLine("Main - Creating worker thread");
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "hi";
        Thread t = new Thread(worker);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Main - Have requested the start of worker thread");
    }
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  But how then do I wait to execute one function until another one is finished?

For example, say I want to execute func_2 only after func_2 is completed, both of which will take several minutes to complete.

Comment: start new thread on the last line of `run_drivers()` method. just stay away from loops on GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could use, while retaining your current code structure, is to update the UI periodically on a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) thread, stopping the timer when the thread completes.  Doing this, you'll change from a loop to an event-driven design, and you'll give the UI thread time to paint your form.

```
// create a System.Windows.Forms.Timer through the designer or in code.
// give it a short interval if you want the counter to increment quickly.

int counter;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    t.Start();
    counter = 0;
    timer.Start();
    ....
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (t.IsAlive)
   {
       counter++;
       toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = counter.ToString(); 
   }
   else
   {
      timer.Stop();
   }
}
```

(Untested)