# Spawned process locks WPF UI

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7, process, inno-setup

When I start a InnoSetup installer from a WPF app, I can't interact with the WPF window until the setup is finished. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406251/running-another-process-without-gui-freezing But the solutions there are based on the fact that the user is starting the process from a GUI thread. I'm starting the process from another thread.

Comment: In fact you are probably starting it also from the UI Thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to wrap the process spawning code for the installer inside ThreadPool.QueueWorkUserItem?

**UPDATE**

Try to decorate your WPF Hosted WCF Service with

```
[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
```

to stop servicing requests on the UIThread and thus make it possible to block on the process handle.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't solve my problem. I need to answer synchronously my WCF client with the process' exit code.

Comment: Or else I'll have to rewrite my WCF contract to answer asynchronously

Comment: Ahh well you should have included that constraint in your original post :) So you have a WPF app that also acts as a WCF Service Host?

Comment: yep... And I find strange that a WCF thread blocks the UI. They seem unrelated.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled that incoming WCF Requests are serviced by the UI Thread. Did you do anything to force this behavior?

Comment: I think I'll vote to close this question as duplicate and start a new question asking how to prevent this "WCF Requests to be serviced by the UI Thread"

Comment: As long as your WCF Requests are serviced on the UI Thread you are pretty much out of luck since blocking on a WaitHandle will of course freeze your UI.